# send http requests in the same session with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am developing my first application in PHP using Curl. The purpose of this application is to develop an HTTP client which sends data to the server.

The server listens to port 10000 on @ 192.168.1.110.

This is the server code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.110';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

//clients array
$clients = array();

do {
    $read = array();
    $read[] = $sock;
    $write = NULL;
    $except = NULL;

    $read = array_merge($read,$clients);

    // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
    if(socket_select($read,$write, $except, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Handle new Connections
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {       

        if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
            echo "socket_accept() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
            break;
        }
        $clients[] = $msgsock;
        $key = array_keys($clients, $msgsock);
        /* Enviar instrucciones. */
        $msg = "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue \n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    }

    // Handle Input
    foreach ($clients as $key => $client) { // for each client       
        if (in_array($client, $read)) {
            if (false === ($buf = socket_read($client, 4096))) {
                echo "socket_read() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client)) . "\n";
                break 2;
            }
            if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
                continue;
            }
            echo "$buf\n";

            $talkback = "Client {$key}: msg '$buf'.\n";
            socket_write($client, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
            //echo "$buf\n";
        }

    } 
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
```

And this is the HTTP client's source code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://192.168.1.110:10000';
$fields_string = "A";
$fields = array(
    'SERIAL_NUMBER ' => urlencode('123456'),
    'HARDWARE_ID ' => urlencode('455FFG'),
    'CODE ' => urlencode('99'),
    //field goes here 
                );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');



$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.1.110:10000");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
crl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);                                                                     
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'test second session !!!!!');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

When I execute this application (client/server), I got this output:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
> Client 16: msg 'POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.110:10000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 52
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> ASERIAL_NUMBER =123456&HARDWARE_ID =455FFG&CODE =99&1HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
> Client 17: msg 'POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.110:10000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 25
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> test second session !!!!!
> ```

The problem is that the HTTP client doesn't send the data in the same session, the client number was incremented [Client 16, Client 17]!!

How to send the data in the same session using Curl?

Answer (score 0):

The session is stored in the cookie of your browser:

[image: Browser cookie]

When you make a server-side Curl request (like in your PHP code) that cookie isn't being replicated.

What you need to do is tell Curl to include a cookie header. You get the current cookie from the `$_COOKIE` array and place it into headers that you send along with the Curl request.

```php
$headers = array();

// Add cookies to headers, if they're present
if(     isset($_COOKIE)     === true 
    &&  is_array($_COOKIE)  === true
    &&  sizeof($_COOKIE)    >   0
) {
    $cookie_header = "Cookie:";

    // Concatenate each cookie key and value like "key=value"
    foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
        $cookie_header .= " ".safestring($k)."=".safestring($v).";";
    }

    $headers[] = $cookie_header;
}

// Add headers to request, if they're present
if(sizeof($headers) > 0) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
```

Comment: I add this code to http client but the same problem persists